# How to install readline using apk

Tags: linux, apk, ipdb

When I try to install readline using apk

```
pip install readline
```

It says

> Failed building wheel for readline

and the output error is

> gcc: error: readline/libreadline.a: No such file or directory

That seems a cyclic dependency.

If I run `apk readline-dev`, I think it gives me .so shared libs.

The background of all this is I'm trying to get auto complete working during ipdb debugging. I might approach this in the wrong way.

Comment: I don't understand the question. were you able to install the readline python package after you had libreadline.a or not ?

Comment: Nope, installing readline will build wheel as a dependency. During compiling it failed to find readline static lib

Comment: If you need Linux support you can try https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

python package readline is renamed to **gnureadline**

Official warning from [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/readline/), you can find gnureadline [here](https://pypi.org/project/gnureadline/)

*WARNING: THIS PACKAGE IS DEPRECATED! It has been renamed to GNUREADLINE to resolve a name clash with the standard library module. The new readline package is here.*

Installing gnureadline through pip

```
pip install gnureadline
```